# Rails form scope and persisted value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, scope

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app that I'm having a problem with.

Basically each record is a Call, and each Call has many units.  A unit being a vehicle which has a status such as (In service, Out of Service, etc).

When creating a call I want only the units that are marked as In Service to be listed for dispatch.  So I created a scope on the Unit model that scopes that:

Unit.rb

```
scope :in_service, lambda { where(status_id: Status.find_by_unit_status("In Service").id)}
```

In my Calls Helper I have a method which selects the Units and appends their unit type and whether or not they are active on another call so dispatchers won't be tempted to double-dispatch a unit.

calls_helper.rb

```
def unit_select
    Unit.active.order("unit_name").map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }
end
```

Here's where the problem comes in.  If I change the helper method to the following:

```
def unit_select
    Unit.active.in_service.order("unit_name").map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }
end
```

Appending the in_service scope method to the unit_select helper, it does indeed select only units that are in service.  This is fine, but when you go to edit the call and if the unit has changed its status since the calls creation, the unit is then pulled off the record in the form

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:unit_ids, unit_select,  {}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'select'}) %>
```

I get why this is happening, as the form is selecting based off of units that have a status of "In Service", but I need to figure out how to get the Unit assignment to persist in the form.

So with some help from a friend we came up with this for the helper method:

```
def unit_select
(@call.units.to_a + Unit.active.in_service.order("unit_name")).map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }
end
```

Now this works, and the Unit persists in the form when you edit regardless of the Unit's status.  Here's where things get weird.

Let's say you edit the record and want to pull the unit off and assign a different unit.  It won't allow you to do that.  It will continue to keep the value of @call.unit_ids no matter what I do.

Here is what the association looks like:
Call.rb

```
has_many :call_units
has_many :units, through: :call_units
```

Unit.rb

```
has_many :call_units
has_many :calls, through: :call_units
```

On top of this I found another problem when creating a return call.  (Basically taking the original call data and creating a return trip based off the initial call.  When creating a return trip it will assign the same unit_id to the call twice in an array.  So it looks like there are two units on the call but they are really the same unit listed twice.  Here is what my return action looks like in the controller.

calls_controller.rb

```
def new_return
    original_call = Call.find(params[:id])
    @call = Call.new(
      caller_name: original_call.caller_name,
      special_equipment_ids: original_call.special_equipment_ids,
      call_status: "open",
      caller_phone: original_call.caller_phone,
      transfer_from_id: original_call.transfer_to_id,
      transfer_from_other: original_call.transfer_to_other,
      facility_from_location: original_call.facility_to_location,
      transfer_to_id: original_call.transfer_from_id,
      transfer_to_other: original_call.transfer_from_other,
      facility_to_location: original_call.facility_from_location,
      patient_name: original_call.patient_name,
      patient_age: original_call.patient_age,
      patient_dob: original_call.patient_dob,
      patient_sex_id: original_call.patient_sex_id,
      insurance_id: original_call.insurance_id,
      nature_id: original_call.nature_id,
      service_level_id: original_call.service_level_id,
      special_equipment_ids: original_call.special_equipment_ids,
      transfer_date: original_call.transfer_date,
      unit_ids: original_call.unit_ids,
      wait_return: "yes",
      parent_call_id: params[:id],

    )
  end
```

So to summarize, I have found a halfway working way to limit only In Service units to be dispatched onto calls but face the following problems;

1. Cannot remove a unit from the call
2. When editing a call a unit won't display in the form unless the unit is In Service status.
3. When creating a return call, it duplicates the unit_id into an array in @call.unit_ids so the unit displays on the call twice.

So I'd like to be able to select only In Service units on a new call, have the unit show up in the form when editing regardless of its status, and also on the return call only have the unit_ids contain one instance of the unit_id that is supposed to be assigned.

I know this is really confusing and would be happy to pair up with someone, chat, or build a gist so you can see my codebase.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as right now I'm hitting a wall.

**Update: 10:44am**

I've tried adding .uniq on the units array and I still have the problem.  My helper method looks like this:

calls_helper.rb

```
 def unit_select
    (@call.units.to_a.uniq + Unit.active.in_service.order("unit_name")).map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }
  end
```

Does this make sense and is this the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to fully understand your problem but I must say I'm a bit confused. Have you tried separating each case in unit_select instead of trying to get the perfect one liner? From what I understand you want to be able to select:

1. Only "In Service" units when the call in the form is a new instance
2. Show any unit when you edit an existing call

Now, as I said I'm not fully sure I understand your problem but it looks like you're trying to do something like that:

```
def unit_select
  units = Unit.active.in_service.order("unit_name")
  if !@call.new_record?
    units += @call.units
  end
  format_unit_select_options(units.uniq)
end

def format_unit_select_options(units)
  units.map do|unit|
    if unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty?
      ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id]
    else
      ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id]
    end
  end
end
```

You should also move

```
Unit.active.in_service.order("unit_name")
```

in the new and edit action of your Call controller to make sure the responsibility of both the helper and the controller are easier to understand.

Now when you create your return call in your calls_controller, have you tried to use uniq on original_call.unit_ids to make sure the id is only there once? That might only fix the symptom and not the root cause but I am having trouble fully understanding your case...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the helper methods.  This is a lot cleaner and is closer to what I need it to do.  So let me clarify a bit.  When a new call instance it should only show units with a status of In Service.  When editing a call (in the event you want to put multiple units on) it should show the Unit currently assigned (regardless of it's status) and a list of In Service Units to add if needed.  I tried using your code and on the return call I'm no longer getting the unit ID assigned twice.  I think we're on the right track here.  I'm sorry if my case was hard to understand, maybe we can pair?

Comment: Let's try to find some time this week to pair. You'll find me on twitter: @mlainez

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!  I'll add you to twitter. @jamesjelinek